# Changing the status bar color on UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to change iOS 8 search bar status bar color but I tried the UIStatusBarStyleLightContent with no luck anyone knows a better way?
[image: Example of how it looks right now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
self.yourSearchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

EDIT :

To change status bar you can either change your Info.plist or override the preferredStatusBarStyle function

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
  <false/>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
  <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

OR

```
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle
    {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
    }
```

Comment: It changed the whole searchbar to white, what I want is to change the status bar color.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 10 (and maybe earlier?), if you have "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to YES in your Info.plist, simply set the preferredStatusBarStyle in the UIViewController that the UISearchController is included in.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

(you don't need to subclass or create a category/extension of UISearchController to override preferredStatusBarStyle... it uses the preferredStatusBarStyle that you set in your UIViewController)